# Issue with my API for my Spring JSON data on call

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, rest

**Problem/Issue:** I need help fixing an issue with my program involving my GET request and retrieving the JSON data for /mealplanner and its sub paths.

**Program:** The application is a test that integrates with an API from Spoonacular website such that I can GET the requests from daily or weekly meal JSON data. It utilizes the RESTController, Java 11, start.spring.io generator, and Maven. Running the program on the localhost should print out the JSON data directly.

**Link:** This is the progress I've made. (Update: Fixed initial issue) https://github.com/NilesDobbs/assignment10

**Goal:** My localhost is retrieving me a status 404 error for both /mealplanner/day and /mealplanner/week endpoints, and my IDE isn't giving me any errors at runtime, so I can't identify the source. Testing in PostMan is yielding similar results. My only hypothesis is that it that something to do with the apiKey, not it's controller

Answer (score 1):

In your getDayMeals method, you are adding the apiKey to fromHttpUrl instead of the baseURL

You should also check that you only add queryParams if the optional is present, otherwise your url will be invalid and the api returns a 404

Comment: Great, it made a bit of progress. Adding your changes no longer retrieves a 404, but the 
JSON data for /day url retrieves null values on host, and the /week path issues a status 500 error.

Comment: This is the error I receive for /week: `Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 9] (through reference chain: com.coderscampus.assignment10.DTO.WeekResponse["week"])`

Comment: I sent a new link above w/ a new repository on GitHub, if you could check it out.